# VBA doesnt go in Else

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3)
fd.Title = "Select A File"
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "CSV File", "*.CSV"

If fd.Show = True Then
    For Each varFile In fd.SelectedItems
        GetFileName = varFile    
        If fd.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox "File choosen = " & fd.SelectedItems.Count
        Else
            MsgBox "No  file  was  selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Whenever I run this in VBA, a prompt open to select a file and if I select any number of files, the program runs properly . While if I click 'cancel' instead of selecting files, the program does not exit the sub and just exists the what may be the error ? Thanks

Comment: Your code does not make any sence to me, you start a for each and you don't say next, then you start an if statement which you do not close. I think that might have something to do with the code not working.

Comment: As @Goosebumbs pointed out, you have two opened `If` statements and only one is closed. I would suspect that your `End If`s are in the wrong place and so your `Else` is being run in the wrong place (that is, the `Else` matches `If fd.Show = True` instead of `if fd.SelectedItems.Count > 0` as you presumably intend).

Comment: -1 The example code doesn't compile!

Comment: Sorry for that. I made the changes but the problem is still there. I just didn't post it right.

Comment: I just tried your code from vba excel and it runs just fine.. even when I click on cancel...

Comment: Ok Thanks for confirming .

Comment: Sorry but there is no message when I click cancel . Even I tried  running on a new module , but when I select a file it does show me the number of files I selected .

Answer (score 1):

In VBA -1 evaluates to True. So your best bet is to do something like this:

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3)
fd.Title = "Select A File"
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "CSV File", "*.CSV"

Dim FileChosen As Integer
FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen <> -1 Then
    MsgBox "No  file  was  selected"
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each varFile In fd.SelectedItems
         MsgBox "File choosen = " & varFile
    End For
End If
```